# what format to use for creating XLST based on XML file with header and related sub section to get single table?

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I'm trying to create a XLST file so that I can use it in an SSIS task to import XML data into my MS SQL database. I'm new to XLST and XML, and all of the instructional videos/google searches seem to cover very basic XML, so I was hoping to get some additional insight on a more complex setup.

My XML has a header section that contains a survey code and then a question_map per code with list of questions.

Then there is a section that contains each survey ID , survey code, and answers to questions that are from the matching survey code in the header.

I've copied an outline of the file below and the desired table output, and am hoping for some help on how to format the XSLT to get the desired result.

```
Data_export
Header                  
recdate             
    start   /start      
    end /end        
/recdate                
surveycount /surverycount           
Question_map                
    Question            
        service /service    
        varname /varname    
        question_text   /question_text  
    /Question           
/Question_map               
/Header                 
Patientleveldata                    
   survey_id    /survey_id          
   client_id    /client_id          
   service  /service        (matched to service in Header to pull list of questions)    
   recdate  /recdate            
   disdate  /disdate            
  Analysis              
    response        (for each question) 
        Varname /varname    
        Value   /value  (answer to each question)
    /response           
  /analysis             
  Demographics              
    response        (for each question) 
        Varname /varname    
        Value   /value  (answer to each question)
    /response           
  /demographics             
  HCAHPS                
    response        (for each question) 
        Varname /varname    
        Value   /value  (answer to each question)
    /response           
  /HCAHPS               
  Comments              
    Response            
        Varname     /Varname
        sentiment   /sentiment
        value       /valeu
    /Response           
  /Comments             
/patientleveldata                   
/data_export
```

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by2pJ.png)

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: This might be slightly outside your wheelhouse, but a better long term solution is to learn how to do it in C#. 1. Build a c# class using something like https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp. 2. Deserialize into that class object. 3. Process the object into either SSIS dataflow or directly into your DB.